# Typescript using too much code to check for undefined variables

Tags: typescript, types

Here's my code:

```
let { firstId, secondId, thirdId } = bigObject || {};
    firstId &&
     secondId &&
      thirdId &&
      api.doStuff({ firstId, secondId, thirdId }).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Is this really the best way to make Typescript work? I tried doing

```
bigObject !== undefined && api.doStuff({...`
```

But it only works if I specifically name the properties used. If I go by this rule, my code will soon become overrun with code that only checks for defined-ness before running the actual functions I need. It's going to be really hard to read what's actually happening if I need to constantly lay out code to make Typescript happy.

Comment: Well, typescript does what it should do; however I can suggest something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDdV4N). Does it work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] where we can drop the code as-is into our own IDEs to see the issue?  Something where `bigObject` and `api.doStuff` are strongly typed would help, so that we're not guessing.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an object back from an API, you will usually want to type check it. There are a number of libraries for this. I think people are using Zod a lot these days. This serves both to validate that the data is shaped like what you expect, and informs Typescript.

I always put the API call in a hook, where I also manage any caching for the retrieved object.

Once it's type checked, you won't run int this situation. And objects created on the front end do not require type checking, generally.

Comment: I have type checked it. The state that the api data gets saved into is `undefined` before the fetch is made, so this object above (`bigObject`), which is cached data from the api call, is undefined before the fetch request gets made. And it's this initial 'undefined' state that Typescript is upset about.

Comment: Ah. I think we may need a little more code to see what you are running into. It would also help to know what error you are seeing.